# Would it make sense to compare glacier fluctuations in New Zealand with Alps or Canadian rockies?

Tags: glaciology, geomorphology, glaciation

If I want to draw parallels between the glacier fluctuations between different glaciers, (considering similar size class, here, small) at
a) New Zealand
b) European Alps
c) Canadian Rocky Mountains
What are the factors I must definitely not miss to avoid the situation of comparing apples with oranges?
Thank you